# Gerund, to-infinitive or bare infinitive? The first thing I wanted to do was

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Which of these sentences is correct:

1. The first thing I wanted to do was **send** you a text.
2. The first thing I wanted to do was **to send** you a text.
3. The first thing I wanted to do was **sending** you a text.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The to-infinitive and bare infinitive work here—the gerund does not.

Comment: Yes. It's controlled by being linked with _to do_, which is an infinitive, and which takes infinitives as complements.

Comment: Your answer would be even better if you explained a bit more and offered some reliable sources for what you say.