# The thing that I want to do is [...]

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I have seen some similar questions on here, mainly [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115659/is-this-sentence-correct-what-i-want-to-do-is-read-this-book) and [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/567896/gerund-to-infinitive-or-bare-infinitive-the-first-thing-i-wanted-to-do-was), but I'm still not completely convinced.

Which of these is correct?:

- "The thing that I want to do is study English"
- "The thing that I want to do is to study English"
- "The thing that I want to do is studying
  English"

I personally think that only the first one is correct despite what people have been saying in the other threads that I have linked as, unlike in the examples given in those questions, something still feels off about using [to] here.

Comment: The third is bad grammar.  The first two are valid grammar, and the choice would be based on context and "tone".

Comment: As @HotLicks says the third one is definitely wrong but there's nothing wrong with either of the others. The repeated 'to' in the second one makes it a bit clumsy, particularly combined with the phrase "The thing that" rather than "What" but that is a style choice rather than a grammatical error.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Right. You need an infinitive, but you can use _to_ or not, because the structure is a cleft. It comes from _I want to study English_, but the cleft has added lots of dummies that don't change the meaning but do change the structure. After _want_, you need _to_; but after the clefting, _study_ doesn't come after _want_ any more; it's after _is_, and there you have a choice, to use _to_ or not (to).

Comment: BTW, none of these is how I think most would say it. More normal would be "I want to study English" or "What I want to do is study English"

Comment: This _does_ answer your question. [Is this sentence correct? "What I want to do is read this book."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115659/is-this-sentence-correct-what-i-want-to-do-is-read-this-book) Professor Lawler studied under McCawley, himself a student of Chomsky.

Answer (score 0):

Go with "The thing that I want to do is to study English."

Or rephrase as

- "Studying English is the thing I want to do."

Or as

- "Studying English is what I want to do."

Comment: Why the extra reduplicated *to* particle for the infinitive clause? A simple *What I want to do is study English* sounds more natural and fluent, as mentioned in comment by Barmar.

Comment: It's courtesy my old English teacher. Q. What do you want to do? A. I want to study. [ I am going to do something. What am I going to do? I am going to read.] If it is possible to use a verb with or without "to" in front of the verb, my teacher advised me and other students to use "to" in front of the verb.

Comment: Then either your teacher gave you poor advice or that advice does not apply to this situation. Although adding *to* in something like *What I want to do is (**to**) pass my exam* or *Could you please help me (**to**) carry this in?* is indeed optional, doing so sounds almost stilted and unnatural. Why? Because people don't actually talk like the android Data from *Star Trek*. :)